# jQuery Hash Change event isn't working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have looked at numerous examples and can't figure out why it isn't hitting my hash change even. For starters, I am using MVC4, jquery 1.8.2. Intellisence isn't picking up hashchange. It's almost like it isn't a feature in the jQuery version.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$( window ).hashchange(function() {
alert('hash change');
});
```

and:

```
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) { alert('hash change'); });
```

Neither one of them work. I am loosing my mind.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
    console.log(location.hash)
}
```

Comment: I replaced the console.log with: alert('here'); It never got executed.

Comment: onhashchange checks for the the window not for jquery $(window)